# How can I check the current tab size in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm using PuTTY and vim and I'd like to know the current tab size.

How can I check that?

Comment: By inserting a `<tab>` and counting the number of empty cells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can append `?` to a command to get the current value. `:set tabstop?` will output the current tab size.